# If ThreadPool is full, how to make Action.BeginInvoke spawn a non threadpool thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5, asynchronous

In .net 3.5

trying to `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(a=> {Work()});` when the ThreadPool has no available threads caused BeginInvoke lock up.

```
void Work()
{
   Action executor = () = { DoSomething(); };
   IAsyncResult result = executor.BeginInvoke(null, null);

   using (WaitHandle hWait = result.AsyncWaitHandle)
   {
      if (hWait.WaitOne(timeoutMilliseconds))
      {
        executor.EndInvoke(result);
      }
      else
      {  throw new ImDyingException(); }
   }
}
```

How can I make the BeginInvoke use a non-pooled thread?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. It sounds like you are vastly over-using the pool. Perhaps consider a throttled queue / custom thread pool (i.e. a synchronized producer/consumer queue)?

(don't increase the pool size; that is almost always the wrong approach to take)

Comment: My problem really only exists with my test harness (which is abusing threadpool), which is attempting to act as a LoadTester against this code